# How to set up Volley with a list or grid adapter

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using Volley in a music player I am trying make.

Here is how I define what a song is in my music player. I have this "song object" with some attributes

```
SongObject {

    public String albumArtURI;

    // Some other attributes 
}
```

I'm using the albumArtURI to populate various list and grid views with images.

To get albumArtURI, I make a query for it. If the URI does not exist, I have to pull an image URL down from the internet.

So I set up Volley to pull down JSON-objects from iTunes, parse the objects, and get their image URLs.

So for example, here is am iTunes JSON object URL which is an address to a webpage containing various JSON objects representing albums by Michael Jackson.

```
String url = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=michael+jackson";
```

Now say I want to use an image URL from one of these JSON album objects for all my songs. If I'm using Picasso to generate images on my lists and grids, then I need to call Picasso within Volley's onResponse method. If there is a better way, please tell.

Here is one of my list adapters

```
SongObject songObject = songObjectList.get(position);

ViewHolder viewHolder; 

if (convertView == null) {
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_view, parent, false);
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
} else {
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

viewHolder.albumArt = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.album_art);

// Here I check if songObject.albumArtURI is null, and use Picasso 

if(songObject.albumArtURI != null){

    File f = new File(songObject.albumArtURI);
    Picasso.with(viewHolder.albumArt.getContext())
            .load(f)
            .transform(new CircleTransform())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.blackcircle)
            .into(viewHolder.albumArt);
} else {

// If songObject.albumArtURI is null, I use Picasso inside Volley's onResponse method 

VolleyClass vc = new VolleyClass(getContext());
vc.runVolley();

}
```

Here is .runVolley() method

```
// Here I set up the request queu

RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ctx);

// Here I make an json object request 

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override

    // Here I use GSON in the onResponse method to parse the object(s)

    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        if (response != null) {
            int resultCount = response.optInt("resultCount");
            if (resultCount > 0) {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.optJSONArray("results");
                if (jsonArray != null) {

                    // Here I parse the JSON object(s) into their Java class 

                    SongInfo[] JSONObjectsList = gson.fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), SongInfo[].class);

                    // Here I use Picasso 

                    Picasso.with(ctx)
                        .load(String.valueOf(JSONObjectsList[0].artworkUrl30))
                        .transform(new CircleTransform())
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.blackcircle)
                        .into(iv);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e("LOG", error.toString());
    }
});

// Here I add the object request object to the queue
```

requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
The code is working, but the problem is that I have a really bad framerate on run time, and if I scroll too quickly in my list view, my app crahses. The error log is at the bottom of this post.

The bad framerate does not appear to be due to Picasso. If I comment out the Picasso code in the onResponse method I get the same behaviour.

I think the problem is that I create a new instance of the requestQueue on every new iteration of my list adapter. I've tried using the singleton approach with no luck.

How can I set up Volley to work with my list adapter and handle a large number of jsonObjectRequests?

```
11-27 01:25:21.482 32167-32182/ I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 157894(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 62(5MB) LOS objects, 9% free, 63MB/69MB, paused 9.954ms total 196.412ms
11-27 01:25:21.502 32167-32167/ D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-27 01:25:21.602 32167-32182/ W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.316ms
11-27 01:25:21.662 32167-32182/ I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 160421(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 36(3MB) LOS objects, 22% free, 55MB/71MB, paused 16.171ms total 156.768ms
11-27 01:25:21.672 32167-32182/ W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.037ms
11-27 01:25:21.712 32167-32174/ W/art: Suspending all threads took: 36.212ms
11-27 01:25:21.732 32167-32182/ I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6365(305KB) AllocSpace objects, 6(372KB) LOS objects, 12% free, 55MB/63MB, paused 11.009ms total 55.466ms
11-27 01:25:21.772 32167-32167/ D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-27 01:25:21.862 32167-32167/ D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-27 01:25:22.062 32167-32167/ D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-27 01:25:22.102 32167-32182/ I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 134151(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 47(4MB) LOS objects, 22% free, 55MB/71MB, paused 11.466ms total 128.496ms
11-27 01:25:22.362 32167-32167/ D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-27 01:25:22.652 32167-32182/ I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 171943(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 86(7MB) LOS objects, 11% free, 59MB/67MB, paused 6.646ms total 90.801ms
11-27 01:25:22.662 32167-32167/ D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-27 01:25:22.712 32167-32174/ W/art: Suspending all threads took: 33.982ms
11-27 01:25:22.742 32167-32182/ I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 124437(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 24(2MB) LOS objects, 23% free, 52MB/68MB, paused 12.255ms total 87.884ms
11-27 01:25:22.932 32167-32167/ D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-27 01:25:23.192 32167-32167/ D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-27 01:25:23.192 32167-32167/ I/Choreographer: Skipped 127 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 01:25:23.342 32167-32182/ I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 152008(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 69(6MB) LOS objects, 12% free, 57MB/65MB, paused 11.857ms total 124.020ms
11-27 01:25:23.702 32167-32174/ W/art: Suspending all threads took: 29.615ms
11-27 01:25:23.772 32167-32182/ I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 165355(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 26(3MB) LOS objects, 21% free, 56MB/72MB, paused 10.798ms total 159.423ms
11-27 01:25:23.852 32167-32182/ I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 16824(674KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(150KB) LOS objects, 12% free, 57MB/65MB, paused 7.395ms total 66.835ms
11-27 01:25:24.182 32167-32174/ W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10.983ms
11-27 01:25:24.562 32167-32182/ I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 60495(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 15(2MB) LOS objects, 20% free, 62MB/78MB, paused 12.542ms total 196.419ms
11-27 01:25:24.632 32167-32182/ I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6414(236KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 11% free, 63MB/71MB, paused 10.624ms total 67.043ms
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ W/libc: pthread_create failed: couldn't allocate 1064960-byte stack: Out of memory
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again"
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime: Process: , PID: 32167
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.volley.RequestQueue.start(RequestQueue.java:145)
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:79)
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:105)
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:115)
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at .ServiceHandler.runVolley(ServiceHandler.java:41)
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at .MyListAdapterTracks.getView(MyListAdapterTracks.java:119)
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2825)
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1884)
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:713)
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:677)
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:7043)
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:6481)
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:559)
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
11-27 01:25:24.932 32167-32167/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
11-27 01:25:25.062 32167-2055/ A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault add
```

Comment: Follow this link may be it will be useful http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Comment: Since the server URL returns an array containing all the imageUrls, so IMO, you only need to make volley request once, then parse and get all the imageurls, then update the list with them.

Comment: @BNK well the URL string will change on every iteration of my list adapter, so I need to make multiple calls to Volley one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you always creating RequestQueues for each request. If that's the case, change your program to use one common instance of RequestQueue. plz refer to this post [Volley Plus OutOfMemoryError in List Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27211417/volley-plus-outofmemoryerror-in-list-adapter)

How about to declare RequestQueue requestQueue outside of the Method and into the Method you check first if requestQueue==null, if this is the case, so initialize it otherwise just make your request.

```
public class VolleyAppController extends Application {

private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

private static VolleyAppController sInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // initialize the singleton
    sInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized VolleyAppController getInstance() {
    return sInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {

    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}

public void addToRequestQueue(Request req) {

    getRequestQueue().add(req);
 }
}
```

now you can use it like this:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
@Override

// Here I use GSON in the onResponse method to parse the object(s)

public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    if (response != null) {
        int resultCount = response.optInt("resultCount");
        if (resultCount > 0) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            JSONArray jsonArray = response.optJSONArray("results");
            if (jsonArray != null) {

                // Here I parse the JSON object(s) into their Java class 

                SongInfo[] JSONObjectsList = gson.fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), SongInfo[].class);

                // Here I use Picasso 

                Picasso.with(ctx)
                    .load(String.valueOf(JSONObjectsList[0].artworkUrl30))
                    .transform(new CircleTransform())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.blackcircle)
                    .into(iv);
            }
        }
    }
}
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    Log.e("LOG", error.toString());
}
});

VolleyAppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
```

hope that help.

Comment: That's what I thought to. You want to show me how to implement the request queue I need?

Comment: Okay, but that method should be static and so should the request queue.

Comment: no it shounldnt. you can create a Singleton Class for your Queue that extends Application and than create a singleton instance of the class for easy access in other places.

Comment: Getting this error `Class 'VolleyAppControler' declared public, needs to be declared in a file named `VolleyAppControler.java'`

Comment: You have to write VolleyAppController in its own class.